# While looping PHP array HTML table properties are missing after first row?

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I am trying to show a shopping cart array in the cart page in a html table, but after first row html table properties are missing. I mean after first row data is not showing as a html table. What's wrong in this code?

```
<?php
  if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
?>
<table border = "1">
  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold">
    <td>Serial</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Options</td>
  </tr>

  <?php
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
      $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'].' EL Kit';
      $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['quantity'];
      $amount = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['amount'];        
  ?>

  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td><?php echo $i+1?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pid?></td>
    <td>$<?php echo $amount?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>                    
    <td>$<?php echo $amount*$q?></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:del(<?php $pid ?>)">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: a little bit messy your code...

Comment: i am looking for why from second row onwards html table is not working

Comment: Try debug with a print_r or var_dump func your $_SESSION['cart'] var to insure that the items is really there.

Answer (score 2):

You `</table>` is repeated in each iteration of your loop , so try to put it after the loop.

```
<?php
        if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
?>
            <table border = "1">
                <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold">
                    <td>Serial</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Qty</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Options</td>
                </tr>
<?php
            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'].' EL Kit';
                $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['quantity'];
                $amount = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['amount'];

?>
                <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <td><?php echo $i+1?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pid?></td>
                    <td>$<?php echo $amount?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>                    
                    <td>$<?php echo $amount*$q?></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:del(<?php $pid ?>)">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>

<?php           
            }
        }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

close the `</table>` after the for loop.